# How to pass HTTP AUTH values via prototype Ajax.Request()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl, xmlhttprequest, prototypejs

Is there any way to pass HTTP AUTH username and password along with an Ajax.request()? Basically, I'm trying to find the equivalent of:

```
curl user:pass http://url.com
```

Is seems this has to be available, but I can't figure it out. If not, is there another JS alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about Prototype, but you can pass the username and password as the fourth and fifth arguments of the underlying `open` method of `XmlHttpRequest`, as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#open()).

Comment: Any chance you could post a sample code snippet here that shows how to manipulate the XmlHttpRequest.open() method directly from Prototype (if you know how)?

Answer (score 0):

I know that someone wrote a user extension for the [ExtJs](http://www.extjs.com) library that provides configuration options for Basic Authentication in standard Ajax requests, and automatically handles the Base64 encoding.

http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=21681